# WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I am implementing a WCF service which eventually runs some stored procedures on a database it calls `BeginExecuteReader` and `BeginExecuteScalar`.
I can not decide which `AsyncWaitHandle` implementation I need. I thought about 2 options:

1. The simple one:

   ```
   public System.Threading.WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
   {
       get
       {
           return m_manualResentEvent;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Which uses a lock to protect `m_ManualResentEvent`

   ```
   public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
   {
       get
       {
           if (m_manualResentEvent!= null)
           {
               return m_manualResetEvent;
           }
           lock (ThisLock)
           {
               if (m_manualResetEvent == null)
               {
                   m_manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(isCompleted);
               }
           }
           return m_manualResetEvent;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The Begin* methods are for async usage. If you're only going to block on the wait handle, it defeats their purpose. Use the synchronous methods instead.

Comment: @CoryNelson-Can you please explain more (I am not sure I understand you)I am implementing wcf.What is an alternative for blocking on the wait handle? As a part of it I should define public class AsyncResult : IAsyncResult.The IAsyncResult interface has AsyncWaitHandle.So I should implement it.The service I am implementing is async and non-blocking. Clients ask for some data which is delivered from the database

Comment: What version .net are you targeting? If you don't need to support 3.5 and below, just use tasks — `Task` implements `IAsyncResult`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy - I know about that.But I need to support .net < 3.5

Comment: Then grab the .net sources or reflector and look how System.Net.LazyAsyncResult is implemented. It is unfortunately internal so you can't derive from it. Also, it is very close to the second example in @acarlon's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As you mentioned in the comments, you are implementing IAsyncResult. I can find two samples from Microsoft [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/06/15/multithreading-implementing-the-iasyncresult-interface.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikos/archive/2011/03/14/how-to-implement-iasyncresult-in-another-way.aspx). In both cases, they went for your option two. I can only think that it was done that way because the ManualResetEvent is not always used, so it saves on resources to only create when needed.

**Original**

The first one seems to have less opportunity for thread contention (waiting for the Lock) without losing anything as far as I can see. I am assuming that in the first option the ManualResetEvent is an instance member that is initialised in the constructor. If so, I would go with the first.

How likely are you to use the event? If it is not likely at all, then you may want to consider the second since it will save you from consuming a resource and the thread contention is unlikely.

Comment: @acarion - I am afraid that using the first one can cause m_manualResentEvent to be corrupted /not read correctly if I have several clents...Can it happen?

Comment: @Yakov - is it an instance variable on the class or static?

Comment: @Yakov - I take it in option 1 that you initialize in the constructor?

Comment: probably I`ll initialize in constructor.But I am not sure that constructor init is the best option - what are the pros/cons of it?

Comment: @Yakov - You would want it to be an instance variable and you would want to do it in the constructor, otherwise other threads call call the instance member that creates the ManualResetEvent and overwrite the existing one.

Comment: @Yakov: just initialize it in your ctor, and make your parent class implement `IDisposable` so that you can dispose the event once no longer needed. I am not sure why you made it `public` though, that part doesn't feel right. You should post the code which is reading from the DB and using this handle, because most likely you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @acarlon I am implementiong wcf. As a part of it I should define public class AsyncResult : IAsyncResult.The IAsyncResult interface has AsyncWaitHandle.So I should implement it.The service I am implementing is async and non-blocking.Clients ask for some data which is delivered from the database

Comment: @acarlon - 10x.I see the examples. My case is a bit different.I am not using ThreadPool,since for I/O (databases) it looks like async over sync.But just call BeginExecuteReader and BeginExecuteScalar.Does it make thing regarding AsyncWaitHandle  use different?

Comment: @Yakov - I wouldn't know the specifics of that, but if I were you I would follow the Microsoft samples (your approach 2) as it should be pretty safe and unlikely to be significantly different. You may want to ask a separate question about the specific differences with respect to AsyncWaitHandle when using database async.

Answer (score 1):

WCF will not use the event anyway because that would destroy any efficiency gains. If you are doing async to gain efficiency and/or scalability, never use the wait handle. Throw a `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: As I understand AsyncWaitHandle is used only by a client to check if the handle is signaled.So it should be up to the client if use or not AsyncWaitHandle ...When you say "WCF will not use the event anyway" - can you explain that a bit more? I understand that WaitHandle is a part of IAsnycResult and it is up to developer of client to make /or not the use of it.

Comment: Note, that client and server are separated by a network protocol that does not know anything about IAsyncResult or WaitHandle. To the client it does not matter how you generate the response on the server. Client and server certainly do not share the same WaitHandle (how could they? What if the server was a Linux PHP app?). Does that make sense to you? Also note, that you can have a sync server and an async client (and vice versa). There is no dependency between the implementation details of both.

Comment: So who can use AsyncWaitHandle - callback?It is a part of IAsyncResult

Comment: The WCF book talks about fallowing (who (can) calls it): CalculatorClient proxy = new CalculatorClient();
IAsyncResult result = proxy.BeginAdd(2,3,null,null);
/* Do some work */
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); //This may block
int sum = proxy.EndAdd(result); //This will not block
Debug.Assert(sum == 5);
proxy.Close();

Comment: As I just said, the client has its own async facilities backed by the OS kernel. The server does not have to do anything. The client can use callbacks and events, always, for every web service in existence. Did you understand what I said? If not, ask.

Comment: I don`t.What I do understand is : the server makes the work asynchronously non blocking, No one needs to wait for the end of its execution.When it finishes it doesn`t push the operation back to the thread pool,but uses the callback.It uses IAsyncResult implementation uniquely identifies the method that was
invoked using Begin<Operation>().IAsyncResult includes inside it AsyncWaitHandle.What for?Who/when can use it?

Comment: If your async method returns an IAsyncResult, the only one who will be consuming it will be WCF. WCF will give you a callback that you call when you're done. At this point WCF will send the result to the client over TCP. Note, that the client has nothing to do with all of this. I'm running out of ways to tell you that. Please ask more specifically about what you do not understand about this principle. Use Fiddler to see the SOAP request being exchanged. Maybe that will help you understand that on the wire async does not exist.

Comment: I understand that point. Thank you!My question is who uses IAsyncResult`s AsyncWaitHandle?(Why AsyncWaitHandle is inside IAsyncResult)

Comment: I don't know. Most of the time it shouldn't be used. You can use it to implement a timeout on network operations (`var a = BeginX(); a.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000); CancelX();`). The callback should be the way to get notified because async is all about *not* waiting and blocking (mostly).; With `Task` the same applies. It also has a WaitHandle that should almost never be used.

Comment: Look here - It uses WaitHandle at End[Operation]()http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/06/15/multithreading-implementing-the-iasyncresult-interface.aspx

Comment: But only `if (!_isCompleted)`. EndX is supposed to be called from the callback. At this point it is guaranteed to be completed. No blocking here. This is analogous to `Task.Wait()` - if completed, it does not block.; Note, that the linked articel shows you lots of ways to use an IAsyncResult - most of which are wrong most of the time. The article tells you what you *can* do, not what you *should* do. You *should* use the callback and only call EndX from the callback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45576/discussion-between-yakov-and-usr)

Comment: take a look at this - it uses the waithandler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx